# Kotlin Android Room Database Delete Query Problem

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, dao

I need some help with my code. I'm trying to delete multiple items by uid from my room database, but even if it's in a loop, it deletes only the first item it finds and that's all...

The sample from my Dao:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM itementity WHERE uid = :itemUid")
fun deleteByUid(itemUid: String)
```

How I delete multiple items:

```
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        itemsObject.forEach {
            db.itemDao().deleteByUid(it.uid)
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM itementity WHERE uid IN (:uidList)")
fun deleteAllInList(uidList: Array<String>)
```

And now You can delete it just by passing `itemsObject` as an argument.

Let me know if it is working, I was doing like that but with `LongArray` not `Array<String>` so I am not sure if it works.